# c# regexp to match property and function

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I need to match 2 types of values:
1. `Object.Property`
2. `Object.FuncName("Argument")`

For now I try to use something like this:
`\w+.\w+(\(.*\))?`
`\w+.\w+` - makes sure I get expressions like Object.PropertyName
`(\(.*\))?` - I get any parentheses with arguments inside. As they are wrapped in parentheses and followed by questionmark this part is optional. 
So it may be `Object.PropName` or `Object.FuncName('SomeArgHere')`

When I use this regex against something like this:
 
`Object.FuncName("SomeArg") = 'SomeValue'  AND Object.SomeProp = 'AnotherValue'`
In [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) I have `'SomeValue'` `AND Object` matched as well. 
Instead it should match `Object.FuncName("SomeArg")` and `Object.SomeProp`

Based on the answer from I tried to use `\w+\.\w+(\(.*?\))?\s+MayContain(\[.+,?\ ?\])` to match against things like: `Obj.Prop MayContain["value"] AND Obj.Func("Test") MayContain["Other"]`. And it match the whole string, in spite of AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dot so that it would match a literal dot otherwise it would match any character other than a newline character.

```
\b\w+\.\w+(\(.*?\))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/34)
[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/4v8zjq)

**Update:**

The below regex would match both type of strings,

```
\w+\.\w+(\(.*?\))?(?:\s+MayContain(\[[^]]*\]))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/37)

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I tried to use `\w+\.\w+(\(.*?\))?\s+MayContain(\[.+,?\ ?\])` based on it to match against things like: Obj.Prop MayContain["value"] AND Obj.Func("Test") MayContain["Other"]. And it match the whole string, in spite of AND. Will update the question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! But what was the problem? It looked like something should be working.

Comment: `.+` would match any character except `\n` one or more times.